# Why do async wcf proxy operations have a different return type

Tags: c#, wcf, client

I have a WCF service that exposes an operation on it.

**Service Interface (Server Side)**

```
[OperationContract]
ResolveAliasResponse ResolveAlias(ResolveAliasRequest request);
```

**Response Object (Server Side)**

```
[DataContract]
public class ResolveAliasResponse : GenericGatewayResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public AliasIdentifier AliasIdentifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AccountDetail AccountDetail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AliasDetail AliasDetail { get; set; }
}
```

On the client side my WCF proxy creates two distinct operations for this - one synchronous and one asynchronous. What I don't understand is why the return types are different.

```
var result = await outgoingClient.ResolveAliasAsync(request);

var result2 = outgoingClient.ResolveAlias(request);
```

**Return types (Client Proxy)**

> result type = ResolveAliasResponse1
>   result.Body.ResolveAliasResult type = ResolveAliasResponse
>
> result2 type = ResolveAliasResponse1

There is nothing in the wsdl about "ResolveAliasResponse1". Why is there additional wrapping on the async methods?